# Linux Mint Desktop Icon won't show

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, desktop-environment

I am running a new install of Linux Mint 19.1.

I have created a desktop icon added to my Linux Mint menu.

I have then went into the desktop file, and manually added an icon.

My problem is that the icon will not show up. The icon is 128x128 pixels, and of png format. The path has been double and triple checked to be correct. I have restarted the PC as well. I can't figure out why the icon image will not work for the desktop icon.

Here is the desktop file I am using...

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Android Studio
Exec=/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
Comment=
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.png
```